# How to Fix DMARC configuration. Email dropping spam folder Google Apps

Tags: email, google-apps, amazon-route53, spf, dmarc

I have a domain set up on AWS Route53 and I use the GoogleApps for the administration of email accounts. I'm having trouble sending invite (Google Calendar/Hangout) to other domains. These invites are going in the SPAM box.

My DNS Configuration

```
$ dig -t any matheuscarino.com.br

;; ANSWER SECTION:
matheuscarino.com.br.   27  IN  A   54.88.183.99
matheuscarino.com.br.   27  IN  A   54.86.206.71
matheuscarino.com.br.   21567   IN  NS  ns-1324.awsdns-37.org.
matheuscarino.com.br.   21567   IN  NS  ns-1966.awsdns-53.co.uk.
matheuscarino.com.br.   21567   IN  NS  ns-691.awsdns-22.net.
matheuscarino.com.br.   21567   IN  NS  ns-7.awsdns-00.com.
matheuscarino.com.br.   867 IN  SOA ns-1966.awsdns-53.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
matheuscarino.com.br.   267 IN  MX  1 aspmx.l.google.com.
matheuscarino.com.br.   267 IN  MX  10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
matheuscarino.com.br.   267 IN  MX  10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
matheuscarino.com.br.   267 IN  MX  5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
matheuscarino.com.br.   267 IN  MX  5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
matheuscarino.com.br.   267 IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"

$ dig -t TXT _dmarc.matheuscarino.com.br

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_dmarc.matheuscarino.com.br. 299 IN TXT "v=DMARC1\; p=quarantine\; pct=100\; rua=mailto:webmaster@matheuscarino.com.br"
```

See how the messages are delivered.

```
spf=pass (google.com: domain of 3J4q7VQIUDdwCSK8RFCSQA8PGLM.AMK.9PK8RFCSQ.P8KMQL8RSC.AMK.9P@calendar-server.bounces.google.com designates 2607:f8b0:4002:c07::24a as permitted sender) smtp.mail=3J4q7VQIUDdwCSK8RFCSQA8PGLM.AMK.9PK8RFCSQ.P8KMQL8RSC.AMK.9P@calendar-server.bounces.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@google.com;
       dmarc=fail (p=QUARANTINE dis=QUARANTINE) header.from=matheuscarino.com.br
Received: by ykdv124 with SMTP id v124so3562561ykd.1
        for <matheus@XXXXX.com.br>; Fri, 31 Jul 2015 07:46:00 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=google.com; s=20120113;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, it looks like the SPF record for this domain has been changed and is currently invalid.  This - `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com matheuscarino.com.br ~all` is not a valid SPF record.

Answer (score 5):

So getting a Google Apps email system to be DMARC compliant requires that you enable domain-specific DKIM.  Right now your email is being DKIM signed with a `google.com` signature, but the FROM header is an `matheuscarino.com.br` address.  So the DKIM signature cannot be used for DMARC authentication, because the domains are not the same.

For most emails sent from your Google Apps account, this isn't a problem, because SPF authentication matches the FROM header domain.  These emails have a Return Path address with a domain of `matheuscarino.com.br`, and your SPF record above authenticates them.

BUT, Calendar and Hangout messages use a different Return Path domain.  So for these messages to authenticate you must enable DKIM for your Google Apps account.  You can find instructions here - https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124?hl=en

Comment: Even with DKIM enabled, emails from google calendar still fails SPF checks

Comment: Yes, even after enabling DKIM for Google Apps accounts, emails sent from calendar-server.bounces.google.com are still not DKIM signed, and they fail DMARC. It looks like there is no solution to this if DMARC has `p=reject` or `p=quarantine` set.

Comment: Even with DKIM enabled in Google Workspace, dmarc still fails on emails with `calendar-server.bounces.google.com` in the `Return-Path`